# Image links in embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url

I'm a little confused.

How would I go about producing this in embedded ruby?

`< a id="example" href="image_tag thing.photo.url" >< img alt="example3" src="image_tag thing.photo.url(:small)" />< /a >`

Comment: hmm... wait a minute... hmm... what?!

Comment: you want to do this with Ruby or Rails?

Comment: yes and i want this format  in order to use a jquery plugin actually, if that helps make it clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to link a set of objects, rather than calling `link_to name, path, options` you can use a block, so you're sending in the method(s) you want it to execute. Use the "do" syntax:

```
<%= link_to thing.photo.url, :id=>'example' do
      image_tag(thing.photo.url(:small), :alt=>"example3")
    end
%>
```

Comment: Thanks!! u got exactly what i wanted